# Resizing VHDX Fixed Disk

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, hyper-v, disk-space-utilization, vhd

I recently converted a Dynamic VHD disk that was 95GB in size(only uses 60GB inside the guest) and now as a fixed disk it is 170GB in size.

How can I resize the newly created fixed disk to under 80GB in size?

I am running Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Provided that it is a VHDX file, try those commands:

`Resize-VHD –Path c:\Disk.vhdx –SizeBytes 80GB`

If that throws an error try:

`Resize-VHD –Path c:\Disk.vhdx –ToMinimumSize`

You cannot shrink a VHDX to less than its minimum size. To get the minimum size:

`(Get-VHD .\disk.vhdx).MinimumSize`